# pass dataset through URL in Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want pass data set through a Laravel URL. This is my code. First I pass my dataset to JavaScript and next I call the URL.

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divClick(roomState, roomCode){
        //  Your code here
        //window.alert(roomCode); //print_output well



        //value_url out put as following
        //room_detail/{"id":"24","room_code":"H5016","roomState":"UnAvailable","hotelId":"5","roomTypeId":"7","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-11-04 06:52:09"}



        //call new page
        window.location.href ="{{url('room_detail/roomCode')}}";

    }
</script>
```

routes.php file code

```
Route::any('room_detail/{roomDetail}', function() {

    return view('pages/room_details/roomMap/single_room_map_detail',  compact('roomDetail'));
});
```

========view.blade.php========================================

I use this code to print passing value.

```
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body">
                     {!! $roomDetail !!}
                </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->

        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

When the view gets rendered, I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: roomDetail
```

Expect some expert help , to pass this data set though a URL .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route needs to look like this (notice the variable in the function call):

```
Route::any('room_detail/{roomDetail}', function($roomDetail) {

    return view('pages/room_details/roomMap/single_room_map_detail',  compact('roomDetail'));
});
```

Also you need to pass the variable correctly to the url like this:

```
window.location.href = "{{url('room_detail')}}" + "/" + roomCode; // maybe you can discard the slash after room_detail.
```

Comment: Thank you sir,error is ok. but now out put show , **value_url** ? I want pass full data set. please expect some help.

Comment: Change this line of code: `window.location.href ="{{url('room_detail/value_url')}}";` `window.location.href ="{{url('room_detail/')}} + value_url";` If you need to use the JSON format you also have to `json_decode` the variable

Comment: when Change that code give big error. **ErrorException in d876d71ce4337316eaa0aefc503f4ddd line 60: Use of undefined constant value_url - assumed 'value_url' ***

Comment: now URL like this . **http://hotel.com/room_detail%20+%20value_url** and given page not found exception.

Comment: You need to move the " right after the PHP call, not at the and of value_url or the variable can't be read by Javascript.

Comment: sorry , your explanation , not understand me.you mean , I couldn't pass this dataset?

Comment: thanks , I change the code  ** window.location.href = "{{url('room_detail')}}" +"/" + roomCode;* * and now details are pass successfully.

Comment: Great! I see you edited your question, I'll change my answer to reflect your changes. Glad we could solve it.